# set total items manually in kendo grid

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm using kendo ui grid with paging. I want to set local data (let's say 10 items) and set total number of items manually (to let's say 100) and can't find how to do it.

Answer (score 5):

I think you should be able to do this by setting the [schema.total](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/framework/datasource#configuration-schema.total) on your DataSource.

Something like:

```
var myData = [...];

var determineTotal = function () {
    return myData.length; // or whatever value you want for the total.
};

var ds = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    data: myData,
    schema: {
        total: determineTotal
    }
});

$("#grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: ds
});
```

Answer (score -1):

we can set total number of items manually using `datasource` `object`

```
  DataSource.total = function (){
                           return 250
                     }
```